# Ruby - unable to write using nokogiri

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I am searching a `<div>` element by its classname and want to add it next to other `<div>` element. Following code is not writing data what I get using doc1.search .

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc1 =  Nokogiri::HTML(File.open("overview.html"))
affixButtons = doc1.search('div.margin-0-top-lg.margin-10-bottom-lg.text-center')
doc1.at('div.leftnav-btn').add_next_sibling(affixButtons)
```

Can someone suggest what I'm missing ?

Comment: I ran your exact code and it worked great for me.. Can you please elaborate where you are stuck? I managed to move the div from the beginning of the code to after the `leftnav-btn` div.

Comment: Do the css selectors select the correct elements? You can print them using something like puts(affixButtons) to make sure.

Comment: @Z-Bone After running this code overview.html page is not getting modified. I can not see any changes.

Comment: @Alien_AV Yes ! It selects the correct elements. I confirmed it - puts affixButtons

Comment: Did you save the resulting doc1 to file? `File.open("result.html", "w"){|f| f.write(doc1.to_html)}`

Comment: @Alien_AV Yes !! It worked as expected. Thank you

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". When asking, we need the minimal code that demonstrates the problem, along with the minimum input data (HTML) and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not saving your resulting HTML to file, you can do it like so:

```
File.open("result.html", "w"){|f| f.write(doc1.to_html)}
```

Comment: You can write it more easily using `File.write("result.html", doc1.to_html)`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works just fine, if you would just like to write the edited data to file use `File.open` as follows:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc1 =  Nokogiri::HTML(File.open("overview.html"))
affixButtons = doc1.search('div.margin-0-top-lg.margin-10-bottom-lg.text-center')
doc1.at('div.leftnav-btn').add_next_sibling(affixButtons)

File.open('output.html', 'w') {|f| f.write(doc1.to_html)}
```

Comment: You can write it more easily using `File.write('output.html', doc1.to_html)`.